# Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established - Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the admin SDK for firebase on my machine. When I try to get the users collection I get `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established`. Writing to firestore also does nothing. How can I fix this?

EDIT
[From the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore?hl=en#node.js-admin-sdk):

> The Firebase Admin SDKs automatically connect to the Cloud Firestore
> emulator when the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is set

I do have that environment variable set but I'm trying to connect to production. How can I instruct the SDK to do this?

```
index.js

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: ""
});

const snapshot =  admin.firestore().collection('users').get().then((snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
}).catch(e=>{
  console.error(e);
});
```

The full error log:

```
PS C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server> node index
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:330:49)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:145:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Caused by: Error
    at CollectionReference._get (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1450:23)
    at CollectionReference.get (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1439:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simeon.ramjit\Documents\projects\controllino-server\index.js:41:57)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 14,
  details: 'No connection established',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned above if the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is set the admin SDK will try to connect to your emulator.

Following [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1162#issuecomment-783300066) I deleted the env variable and restarted my terminal and it connected to production successfully